# Spring Boot default settings do not allow me to autogenerate a new class in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Just switched to the Intellij Ultimate 14.1.4 IDE.  Tried to build a simple Spring Boot helloworld endpoint but ran into several problems.

I first created a new Spring initializer project with no issues.  I went through the various windows setting up the project with no issues.  When the project was created it did not generate a Spring Boot main application class, which is no big deal; it's just an irritation for a newbie.

I selected src > file > new and tried to select a Java class but found that there was none in the drop down box.  Most of the drop downs were JavaScript, CSS, and JSON files.  I guess I do not have the correct default for Spring Boot.  Anybody know how to set this up?

Comment: The only thing I can see in the wizard is a straight-up Spring project, not Spring Boot.  So I have my doubts in that you created a Spring Boot project.  Here's one way to tell:  If you have a file called `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, do you see an entry that reads `spring-boot-starter-web`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the build.gradle.  I inspected it and it does have "spring-boot-starter-web".  I have years of experience with Eclipse Spring Boot.  The overall project looks like a spring boot based on what I usually see with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that you were not running that command in the context of a source or test folder.  If you attempt to do any autogenerate commands in a non-source folder, you won't get the full set of things that can be generated.

The simple fix is to be sure that you're in the right folder - likely `src/main/java`.

If the folder isn't marked blue, then right-click on it, and select Mark Directory As > Sources Root.

This is what it appears when you don't have the folder marked as source:

[image]

...and this is what it looks like when you *do*:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what happened but I started getting the main class generated.  However, when I select src/main/java I get the first dropdown you show in your response.  When I create a plain old java project I do get the correct dropdown.  Is there some sort of default I need to be setting?

Comment: Here is the screenshot !Screen Shot 2015-09-09 at 7.39.28 PM.png